# xquery fn:current-date() formate

Tags: xml, xquery

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<library>
    <books>
        <book>
            <title>The Story of my Life </title>
            <accessionNumber val="1"/>
        </book>
        <book>
            <title>XML Schema </title>
            <accessionNumber val="2"/>
        </book>
        <book>
            <title>C++ for Image processing</title>
            <accessionNumber val="3"/>
        </book>
    </books>
    <loans>
        <loan book="1" user="35" dueDate="25-April-2010"/>
    </loans>
    <loans>
        <loan book="3" user="400" dueDate="05-Jan-2010"/>
    </loans>
    <loans>
        <loan book="2" user="02" dueDate="25-Feb-2010"/>
    </loans>
    <users>
        <user>
            <name>Fred Jame</name>
            <id val="35"/>
        </user>
        <user>
            <name>Ashley</name>
            <id val="400"/>
        </user>
        <user>
            <name>Patrick</name>
            <id val="02"/>
        </user>
    </users>
</library>
```

My tasks is to write XQuery Expression which list all users whose loan is overdue.

I have to use `fn:current-date()` function to compare with `dueDate` to find out all overdue users but problem here is `fn:current-date()` format and `dueDate` format in XML document is totally different.

How can I format it to get my desire result?

```
for $x in doc("library.xml")/library
where  $x/@dueDate > fn:current-date()
return $x/@name
```

I tried above but `fn:current-date()` giving date output as `2014-03-30Z`

but I need to compare dueDate with current date if dueDate is above the Current-Date, then shows all  users.

Comment: Have a second look at the solution sketch I described in my answer. You cannot directly compare the date as provided in the XML with the current date.

Answer (score 0):

As this is obviously an exercise, I will not provide a full answer, but sketch for the solution.

1. The date format used in the XML document can hardly be compared. It might be reasonable to create a function which performs following steps (but this could of course also be done without one):

   - You will have to `tokenize(...)` it, resolve the month to numbers and concatenate it as `YYYY-mm-dd`
   - Now you can use `xs:date($string)` to convert it to a date object.
2. Now loop over all `<loan/>` elements and filter them for due loans in there `where` clause, either calling the function you wrote or putting the code here.
3. As last step, you will have to resolve the `<loan/>` objects to the respective users.

This should help you writing the code. If you have any further, specific questions or run into problems, feel free to post follow-up questions (with what you tried)!

---

Update: This is my code, using `index-of` to look up the month. The `resolveDate` function is commented in the code, the remaining query is trivial.

```
declare function local:resolveDate($date as xs:string) as xs:date {
  (: Month index, so we can look it up :)
  let $months := ("Jan", "Feb", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
  (: Split up the date :)
  let $date := tokenize($date, '-')
  (: Resolve the month to its two digit number :)
  let $month := index-of($months, $date[2]) cast as xs:string
  let $month := if (string-length($month) < 2)
                then concat('0', $month)
                else $month
  (: Construct an xs:date object from the reordered date :)
  let $date := string-join(($date[3], $month , $date[1]), '-')
  return xs:date($date)
};

for $user in //user
for $loan in //loan[@user=$user/id/@val]
where local:resolveDate($loan/@dueDate) < current-date()
return $user
```

Comment: The function is called `tokenize`, not `tokenise`. Also, I'd go for tokenizing a dash, not whitespace: `tokenize("25-April-2010", '-')`.

Comment: I am trying to use tokenize() to break dueDate into number but error .

Comment: Please read on how to post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org), so somebody can actually answer your question. As your question is a new, separate one, best would be to actually post one, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function like:

```
declare function local:xml_month

($monthId as xs:string) as xs:string
{
if (tokenize($monthId,"-")[2] = 'January')
then  
concat(  tokenize($monthId,"-")[1],"-",
replace(tokenize($monthId,"-")[2],'January','01'),"-",
tokenize($monthId,"-")[3])
else if (tokenize($monthId,"-")[2] = 'February')
then  
concat(  tokenize($monthId,"-")[1],"-",
replace(tokenize($monthId,"-")[2],'February','02'),"-",
tokenize($monthId,"-")[3])
else if (tokenize($monthId,"-")[2] = 'March')
then  
concat(  tokenize($monthId,"-")[1],"-",
replace(tokenize($monthId,"-")[2],'March','03'),"-",
tokenize($monthId,"-")[3])
else if (tokenize($monthId,"-")[2] = 'April')
then  
concat(  tokenize($monthId,"-")[1],"-",
replace(tokenize($monthId,"-")[2],'April','04'),"-",
tokenize($monthId,"-")[3])
else if (tokenize($monthId,"-")[2] = 'May')
then  
concat(  tokenize($monthId,"-")[1],"-",
replace(tokenize($monthId,"-")[2],'May','05'),"-",
tokenize($monthId,"-")[3])
else if (tokenize($monthId,"-")[2] = 'June')
then  
concat(  tokenize($monthId,"-")[1],"-",
replace(tokenize($monthId,"-")[2],'June','06'),"-",
tokenize($monthId,"-")[3])
else if (tokenize($monthId,"-")[2] = 'July')
then  
concat(  tokenize($monthId,"-")[1],"-",
replace(tokenize($monthId,"-")[2],'July','07'),"-",
tokenize($monthId,"-")[3])
else if (tokenize($monthId,"-")[2] = 'August')
then  
concat(  tokenize($monthId,"-")[1],"-",
replace(tokenize($monthId,"-")[2],'August','08'),"-",
tokenize($monthId,"-")[3])
else if (tokenize($monthId,"-")[2] = 'September')
then  
concat(  tokenize($monthId,"-")[1],"-",
replace(tokenize($monthId,"-")[2],'Sempter','09'),"-",
tokenize($monthId,"-")[3])
else if (tokenize($monthId,"-")[2] = 'October')
then  
concat(  tokenize($monthId,"-")[1],"-",
replace(tokenize($monthId,"-")[2],'October','10'),"-",
tokenize($monthId,"-")[3])
else if (tokenize($monthId,"-")[2] = 'November')
then  
concat(  tokenize($monthId,"-")[1],"-",
replace(tokenize($monthId,"-")[2],'November','11'),"-",
tokenize($monthId,"-")[3])
else if (tokenize($monthId,"-")[2] = 'December')
then  
concat(  tokenize($monthId,"-")[1],"-",
replace(tokenize($monthId,"-")[2],'December','12'),"-",
tokenize($monthId,"-")[3])    
else "NA"
};

for $u in doc("ques2010.xml")//user
for $l in doc("ques2010.xml")//loan    
where fn:current-date() > xs:date(local:xml_month($l/data(@dueDate)))
and $u/id/@val = $l/@user
return $u/name
```

It should work for you.

Comment: You can do, compare with my version of the code I added after some own effort was shown.